# Is the infinite complex projective space related to a projective separable Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projective-geometry, projective-space

For $H$ a Hilbert space, let $P(H)$ denote its [projective Hilbert space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space). Let $\mathbb CP^\infty$ be the infinite complex projective space (eg constructed inductively as a CW complex). Note that $\mathbb CP^{d-1} = P(\mathbb C^d)$. Analogously, if $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, eg $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, is $P(H)$ related to $\mathbb CP^\infty$?

Comment: They're at least weakly homotopy equivalent, and I think likely homotopy equivalent.